# JS syntax on style property

Tags: javascript

Please take a look at my small script that checks if a style is defined on an element already .

HTML :

```
<div id="la" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;background: #eee;">

</div>
```

And the JS :

```
 var _str = document.getElementById('la');

 /*A object literal that contains some pretty random set of css definitions */
 var str_elem = {
        'padding' : '40px',
        'width'    : '100px'    
    }


  /*we are using the for loop to check if the properties defined in our obj literal are actually present in the element style definition.*/
  for(var name in str_elem){
    if (_str.style[name] == ' ') {
        console.log('not present' + ' ' + str_elem[name] );
    }
   }
```

My question is about the if condition and the syntax inside it. Usually when we want to get an elements style we use the following syntax:

```
elementname.style.propertyname
```

But why, when checking if the element has a property, are we using the following syntax:

```
elementname.style['padding']
```

??

And why does this syntax throw an error :

```
elementname.style.propertyname
```

My script works fine, my question is about the JS syntax.

**EDIT::** to condense my difficulty , let me rephrase my question : 
if in the if condition that i have i use the following syntax :

`_str.style.[name]` (note the dot after style) , instead of what i currently have `_str.style[name]` , Why is an error thrown . ?

Comment: Where are you doing this?--> elementname.style['padding'] in your code.

Comment: @SandeepNayak , check my comment in the fiddle against the if condition . http://jsfiddle.net/okkz6hfk/ .

Comment: To learn more about this, have a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to check that the **value** of the `name` variable is present as a style in your element. If you write `_str.style.name`, you would be checking the definition of the style called `name`. Brackets allows you to dynamically check the property, or to check property with hyphens, for example `_str.style['my-dashed-property']`

By the way, considering that the style property is not present because it equals a blank string is weird.

The syntax `obj.[name]` does not work because the dot operator is for accessing properties via fixed keys, hence you look for a property called `[name]` and that is not allowed

Comment: check the fiddle and my comment against the if condition , http://jsfiddle.net/okkz6hfk/ , thats basically my question . thanks for the answer though .

Comment: I see, so you're wondering why `obj.[name]` does not work. Thats because the dot operator is for accessing properties via fixed keys, hence you look for a property called `[name]` and that is not allowed

Comment: so for dynamically looking up properties and also while using the [] brackets , we got to eliminate the dot ?

Comment: thats my answer then .

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see the confusion you have.

Before everything else, read this article.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

In JavaScript, you can access the properties of any variable in two ways.

1) obj.propertyName

2) obj['propertyName']

Now, coming to your question:

```
 _str.style.[name] // Error is thrown because it is syntactically wrong to be accessing the object properties like this.
```

Just `console.log` your `_str.style` and observe that it is an object.

So,

```
_str.style.[name] // Does not make any sense, syntax wise. Hence the SyntaxError.
```

And since, you are trying to access the object properties dynamically inside for loop,  you write like this:

```
_str.style[name] // Here name is a variable whose value is dynamically set during each iteration of the loop.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer dude , i'll +1 you , but will accept Micheals answer as he asnwered 1st :)

Comment: Sure, my answer is an extension to his. I added few references to clear the air. BTW, I too +1ed Michael's answer.